# ImageMagick Set Background Colour

Tags: image, imagemagick, png, jpeg, imagemagick-convert

I am attempting to use the following line of code to set the background colour of Image 1 to white.

(I.e. The first image 'Image1.png' needs to be cleared and become a blank white image. I then overlay Image 2 on top of this blank image)

Here is the line of code I am running in command line:

```
convert \( Image1.png -background white \) \( Image2.png -resize 250x105 \) -geometry +347+400 -composite -format jpg -quality 90 Image1.png
```

Alternatively, it would be better if I could generate a blank canvas for Image2.png to be placed upon. But I would like to get my first attempt using 2 images working first.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you are trying to do, or how big `image1` and `image2` are supposed to be, but this should get you going if I just make up some stuff:

```
# Create image2 as red square coz I don't know better
convert -size 100x100 xc:red image2.png

# Create blue canvas and read in image2, resize it and splat it on top
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:blue \
       \( image2.png -resize 250x105\! \) \
       -geometry +347+400 -composite out.png
```

[image]

If you want to use `image1` rather than create an empty canvas (presumably because `image1` already has the correct dimensions or something), you can use it with my command like this whilst setting it to completely white in the process :

```
convert image1.png -evaluate set 65535 \
        \( image2.png -resize 250x105\! \) \
       -geometry +347+400 -composite out.png
```